# What does TRWP backup include?

Tags: backup, twrp

If I would take a backup via TRWP, does it include all my apps, app data, messages, contacts or it would just take backup of the ROM only, so I could get a fresh ROM with factory restored when I restore it ?

Comment: Not including `/data/media` in TWRP was a truly moronic decision.

Comment: TWRP will backup all apps and data except `/data/media` unless you use Magisk module "TWRP helper" or solution mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200713/131553)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To my knowledge, TWRP does a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup). As you can read in the tag wikis of the mentioned tags ([nandroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info), [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)), a *Nandroid backup* takes images of your partitions. It's not a backup on the file level, but on partition level. So it includes everything stored on those partitions. Doing a full *Nandroid* backup of your system thus includes the entire system, one file per partition. There are only very few things not contained, such as the [radio-firmware](/questions/tagged/radio-firmware).

So to put it as a short direct answer to your question: Yes, a full *Nandroid* backup would include all your *apps, app data, messages, contacts*.

Though it might be complicated to extract them separately (*Nandroid* can't do that, it's always an "all-or-nothing". But e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) can read data from *Nandroid* backups. Just in case you'll need that :)

Comment: what about media -> photos, videos?

Comment: Well, aren't those stored on the device, @jj_? If a Nandroid backup includes all storage, why should it skip a folder when doing an "all-or-nothing" (except when skipping "all" due to some error occuring)? Please see our [backup](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) and [nandroid](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info) tag-wikis for details.

Comment: wait a second, this is actually getting less clear :) `Yes, a full Nandroid backup would include all your apps, app data, messages, contacts.` - Does it also include the files on the sd-card (images, videos, downloaded content, some app content)?

Comment: @jj_ No. Nandroid backups concentrate on *device storage* – external storage usually is not included.

Comment: How do you link to tags, like that?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov should be in the help. Just hit the [edit] link to find out :) `[tag:backup]` iit is.

Answer (score 5):

It is very important to answer this question correctly as many people rely on this backup. Until when you actually need it, you realize that it is not exactly what you think it is, which is disastrous.

Let me answer this question very clearly for everyone:
TWRP backup does include apps and their data **BUT skips media files such as your pictures, videos and music!**

I took a full TWRP backup before I sent my phone to service. When it was back, I restored the backup. My phone started like it was before. Soon after I realized that my photos and music was completely gone. I looked everywhere in my phone but there was nothing left from my pictures! Luckily, I for some reason had a hunch about it and copied my photos separately. And music can be restored easily. (Although I remembered that after 3 weeks that I made a separate copy of my photos). It really hurts!

It backs up data partition but for some reason skips the /data/media folder.

[Another discussion on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2355517)

[Most importantly the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/276)

Comment: You are right TWRP will backup all apps and data except `/data/media` unless you use Magisk module "TWRP helper" or solution mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200713/131553)

Answer (score 4):

TWRP does NOT backup internal media.  TWRP specifically states it will not backup /data/media.   See https://twrp.me/faq/backupexclusions.html.

"To be absolutely clear when you do something like this:

```
Creating a full backup in TWRP (including /data partition)
Factory resetting your phone
Restoring your previously taken full backup
Result: all your saved data will be there but your data on the internal storage gets LOST!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can backup System,Data,Boot,Recovery,Cache,efs

System , Data , Boot are selected by default which includes your ROM , Apps , Appdata , Kernel and you can choose to backup Recovery , Cache , efs which bundles things on your internal SD card like your contacts and photos and videos. TWRP also provides compression which is pretty handy if your backup becomes large.