# Does TWRP backup all apps and data, as opposed to ADB?

Tags: adb, backup, twrp

I need to backup every single user installed app, beyond system apps.

I have heard that `adb backup` will only backup some of these apps (the ones which allows it). Although, I'm not sure if this is the case with TWRP. **Is it?**

I want to make sure that when I restore, I won't have to download apps and configure them, again. **If TWRP can't achive this, what can I do, alternatively?**

---

Currently, I am running this command to backup with TWRP:

`adb backup -f data.ab --twrp compress data system`

**Do I need to include any other partition?**

Comment: @beeshyams I was thinking about doing both ADB and TWRP backups. But now I think this is not necessary. Right? // Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What does TRWP backup include?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43410/16575) should answer the question I guess :) For more, see [these questions](/questions/tagged/twrp+backup).

Comment: @alecxs can you elaborate or reference why it is not important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user [@beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams), answered correctly, in the comments. However, this person did not want to answer, directly.

Here's the answer:

> ADB will not [backup a lot of things](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553).

> TWRP will backup all apps and data except `/data/media` unless you use [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200713/131553) or Magisk module "TWRP helper".

> TWRP is far more reliable in backing up than using adb to backup.

> TWRP will also backup apps and their config. Have a look at our [nandroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nandroid) tag, it's questions and read the tag wiki.

> Back up all partitions. It's while restoring you may skip partitions depending on what you are trying to do.

> I wouldn't do ADB because: a) it won't backup everything; b) I don't know much about it; C) why bother when there is a proven solution in my view?

**UPDATES**

1. @alecxs says:

> It's better to keep one single partition per backup.ab file because some older TWRP have issues with restoring.